# Domain decomposition w/Lagrange multipliers

Tags: domain-decomposition

I'm looking at FEM discretizations of
$$u_i - \Delta u_i = f$$ 
for $u_1, u_2$ on subdomains $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ with interface $\Gamma$. A Neumann-Neumann transmission condition can be formulated by solving for a flux $\lambda$ on $\Gamma$ such that $n\cdot \nabla u_1 = \lambda = -n\cdot \nabla u_2$. One "dual" variational form involves formulating the problem using a Lagrange multiplier unknown $\lambda$, such that

$$\begin{align*}
a_1(u_1,v_1) + a_2(u_2,v_2) + \int_{\Gamma} \lambda [[v]]&= (f,v1)+(f,v2)\\
\int_{\Gamma} \mu [[u]] &= 0
\end{align*}$$
and we can eliminate $u_1, u_2$ to solve only in terms of $\lambda$.

Is there a way to do this for other transmission conditions? I can repeat the same process with for Robin interfaces and add $\alpha u_i$ to the interface BCs. Redefining a new Lagrange multiplier $\tilde{\lambda}$ gives
$$
\begin{align*}
-\alpha u_1 - n\cdot\nabla u_1 &= \tilde{\lambda} = \lambda - \alpha u_1\\
\alpha u_2 - n\cdot\nabla u_2 &= \tilde{\lambda} = -(\lambda - \alpha u_2).
\end{align*}
$$
but the second BC is no longer coercive (the boundary term contributes negative $\int_{\Gamma}\alpha u_2v_2$ to $a_2(u_2,v_2)$). Is there a way to do a stable Lagrange multiplier formulation for the Robin-Robin case for elliptic problems?

(I'd also be grateful for a reference to previous work if I've overlooked the answer to this in literature.)

Comment: If no answer appears in a while, it might be good to add a few more definitions to make the question accessible to a wider audience.

Comment: I'm not sure there is really an answer - the literature I've seen seems to imply that dual formulations aren't used with Lagrange multipliers. You can update Lagrange multipliers using Robin-Robin transmission conditions, but can't formulate Robin-Robin conditions using Lagrange multipliers.

Sorry if it was a bit unaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer to the question is no; however, [Japhet, Maday and Nataf](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/130912621) have come up with a way to formulate Robin transmission conditions in tandem with a Neumann-Neumann Lagrange multiplier approach.

The approach appears to be:

- initialize $u_0, \lambda_0$ by solving the standard Neumann-Neumann problem with Lagrange multipliers. $\lambda$ represents $\pm n\cdot \nabla u_0$ for Poisson.
- given $u_0,\lambda_0$ on a given element face, compute $u_1,\lambda_1$ by solving a local problem 
  $$(\nabla u_1,\nabla v_1) + (u_1,v_1) - \int_{\partial K}\lambda_1,v = (f,v)$$
  $$\int_{\partial K}(\lambda_1 + \alpha u_1^-)\mu = \int_{\partial K}(\lambda_0 + \alpha u_0^+)\mu$$
  where $u_0^+$ is the previous $u$ on the neighboring element, so that information is transmitted across element faces.
- Repeat until converged.